# tag <c:forEach/> si not doing anything

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to show through JSP code the value of some variables stored in in ArrayList money. 
I am using Java for this project. 
The thing is that when I try to do:

```
<c:forEach var="pos" items="${yourGame.money}">
    <c:out value="${pos.nombre}"/>
     ${pos.nombre}: <a href="${pos.url}"><b>${pos.precio}</b></a>
<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

It shows nothing, and I have made sure that yourGame.money isn't empty so I don't know what's going on. I am new to JSP and have run out of ideas; could anyone please help me?

This are the structures I am using:

```
public class Juego{
    String nombre;
    String plataforma;
    String edicion;
    ArrayList<Precios> money = new ArrayList();
}

public class Precios{
    String precio;
    String url;
    String nombre;
}
```

The JSP class recieves a "Juego" object, and I am trying to print the values of the "money" atribute. I know the class JSP is recieving the "Juego" object fine since I have already printed some other variables of this class such as :

```
<h3>The ultimate edition: ${yourGame.edicion}</h3>
```

And it works just fine ...`enter code here`

Comment: I have also added
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
at the beginning of my JSP file...

Comment: What happens if you output `money` itself, or the size of it? E.g. `<h3>Money: ${yourGame.money}</h3><h3>Size: ${yourGame.money.size()}</h3>`

Comment: It shows the correct size of the array.......it isn't empty :&

Comment: Well, then, even if all the string fields of `Precios` are empty strings, you should at the very least see that many `:` colons in the generated page. --- But you never showed what the output of the list itself was. If `Precios` has an adequate `toString()` implementation, that output would be important to see, so you should **edit** the question and show what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your variables to use private access and generate get and set methods for all of them. The issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cross check your controller/Action classes and ensure you are setting money attribute in this yourGame bean and this bean is stored in request or session properly.

This is the only place where I suspect, you might have missed something. Apart from this you jsp looks fine to me.

One more point to check, can you try to print like this 
`<c:out value="${yourGame.edicion}"/>` 
just wanted to make sure the core tag is working fine in your jsp.